# How can I read the mp3 into bytes array

Tags: c#, naudio

I want to use the NAudio with MP3FileReader object 
to read the mp3 into bytes array then i'll try to fft it to create spectrum analyser
but i can't find any documentation about its method.
Do you have any suggestion or any example?

Comment: If your first pass over the mp3 file needs to treat it as a byte array, why would you use an MP3FileReader object for that pass?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[File.ReadAllBytes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.io.file.readallbytes%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) will read a file into byte array:

```
 var bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(fileName);
```

Answer (score 1):

MP3 is encoded.  Performing a FFT on an MP3 would just scramble the data.  Decode first, remove meta data, then read into an array as samples.  Be sure the element size is the same as the sample size.

MATLAB and Octave are great for signal processing.

Sorry, don't have any NAudio experience.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, i will try much more on the research *-*

Answer (score 0):

To pass the audio into an FFT, you will need it to be converted to PCM first. The `Mp3FileReader` that comes with NAudio does this automatically. So when you call `Read` you will get 16 bit PCM as a byte array. If you use `AudioFileReader` instead, you can get the samples as floats, normalised into the +/- 1.0 range, which is ideal to pass into an FFT (although you need to calculate the FFT of each channel separately). If you look at the source code for the NAudio WPF project you will see that it uses an FFT to create a spectrum analyser.